# How server replies to more number of clients from the same port number for same and different type of process?

Tags: java, network-programming

I am having doubt that whether the server connected to different clients processing the same process can send data to more number of clients use different ports for transferring  data to clients or same port for transferring and explain little about assigning of ports in terms of different process also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually works thanks to Threads.
You could think of a thread as if it was another instance of a function of your process.
Whenever a client connects to a single server process, a thread is instantiated and it will have the job to keep the connection, exchange data etc with the user.
You could have a thread for each user, basically.

However, this is not always possible, so callbacks come in handy.
Callbacks are asynchronous functions which get usually called after an event (such as "Packet received"), so there are no threads in this case, but you should be careful for data integrity (callbacks may return values even if you didn't receive the full data yet) and race conditions.

Please correct anything wrong in this answer.

TLDR: You only have one port on the server, and on that port there's the service which could work in any of the two ways. (Client's port might change, but that's nothing to worry about if you are working with TCP)